# how to get CRX file for an extension that is not registered with the Chrome web store?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, crx

I am currently developing a program using Python's Selenium module, which requires an extension program.

Therefore, I need the CRX file of the extension to use it, but the extension I have is not registered in the Chrome web store.

I have an extension file, is there any way to convert this file to CRX?

Thank you and I'm sorry that my English is not good.

Comment: There's no need for CRX because you can unpack the extension and load it directly from disk, there's a lot of examples around.

Comment: The extension must be converted to a CRX file, not just installed.

Comment: Why is that? No one else needs that usually. Anyway, you can do it in chrome://extensions page, see [Chrome extension - Can I share my extension as crx file for using someone?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52742512)

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! have a nice day!